# Как достать уникальные значения из Realm на Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, filter, фильтры, realm

Как достать уникальные значения из Realm на Swift?
У меня есть класс и в свойстве `newsCategory` есть повторяющийся значения

```
class News: Object {

dynamic var newsID: String = ""
dynamic var newsTitle: String = ""
dynamic var newsFullText: String = ""
dynamic var newsImage: String = ""
dynamic var newsAutor: String = ""
dynamic var newsCommentCount: String = ""
dynamic var newsSeenCount: String = ""
dynamic var newsDate: String = ""
dynamic var newsCategory: String = ""

override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "newsID"
}
```

Мне надо достать из базы уникальные категории новостей из `newsCategory`.

Пытался так

```
let realm = try! Realm()
let news = realm.objects(News)
let filter = news.filter("newsCategory")
```

Не получается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот решил

```
extension Results {

func uniqueValueForObject<U : Equatable>(objectKey: String, paramKey: String, type: U.Type)->[U]{
    var uniqueValues : [U] = [U]()
    for obj in self {
        if let o = obj.valueForKeyPath(objectKey) {
            if let v = o.valueForKeyPath(paramKey){
                if(!uniqueValues.contains(v as! U)){
                    uniqueValues.append(v as! U)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return uniqueValues
}

func uniqueValue<U : Equatable>(paramKey: String, type: U.Type)->[U]{
    var uniqueValues : [U] = [U]()
    for obj in self {
        if let val = obj.valueForKeyPath(paramKey) {
            if (!uniqueValues.contains(val as! U)) {
                uniqueValues.append(val as! U)
            }
        }
    }
    return uniqueValues
}

func uniqueObject(paramKey: String)->[Object]{
    var uniqueObjects : [Object] = [Object]()
    for obj in self {
        if let val = obj.valueForKeyPath(paramKey) {
            let uniqueObj : Object = val as! Object
            if !uniqueObjects.contains(uniqueObj) {
                uniqueObjects.append(uniqueObj)
            }
        }
    }
    return uniqueObjects
  }
}
```

Потом используем

```
let unique1 = try! Realm().objects(News).uniqueValue("name", type: String.self)
let unique2 = try! Realm().objects(News).uniqueValueForObject("subItem", paramKey: "name", type: String.self)
let unique3 = try! Realm().objects(News).uniqueObject("subItem")
```